# List of pre-compiled contracts

Tags: contract-development, precompiled-contracts, documentation

Where can I find an authoritative/"official" listing of the pre-compiled contracts currently on the Ethereum network, along with their exact specifications? I couldn't find anything in the [official documentation](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/), but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. Ideally, I'm looking for a list that will be kept up-to-date (as new EIPs will get approved).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here are the precompiled contracts, the numbering is the address of the contract:

1. Recovery of ECDSA signature
2. Hash function SHA256
3. Hash function RIPEMD160
4. Identity
5. Modular exponentiation ([EIP 198](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-198.md))
6. Addition on elliptic curve alt_bn128 ([EIP 196](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-196.md))
7. Scalar multiplication on elliptic curve alt_bn128 ([EIP 196](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-196.md))
8. Checking a pairing equation on curve alt_bn128 ([EIP 197](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-197.md))
9. BLAKE2b hash function ([EIP 152](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-152))

---

A definitive list and specification is the Ethereum [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper).

The first 4:

> ... so-called ‘precompiled’ contracts, meant as a
> preliminary piece of architecture that may later become native
> extensions. The four contracts in addresses 1, 2, 3 and 4 execute the
> elliptic curve public key recovery function, the SHA2 256-bit hash
> scheme, the RIPEMD 160-bit hash scheme and the identity function
> respectively.

As the protocol is updated, the Yellow Paper will also get updated.

[Here is a blog post](https://medium.com/@bekahoxoo/precompiles-solidity-e5d29bd428c4) with examples of using the next 4 precompiled contracts.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out Appendix E of the Yellow Paper is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Why does the contract at address 1 not have any source code? https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001 is the source published somewhere?

Comment: @pinhead They don't have EVM bytecode: their source code is in the clients themselves, for example [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/261b3e235160d30cc7176e02fd0a43f2b60409c6/core/vm/contracts.go#L66)

Answer (score 23):

And in the (Geth) code, they can be found in [`contracts.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/bd6879ac518431174a490ba42f7e6e822dcb3ee1/core/vm/contracts.go#L51):

```
// PrecompiledContractsByzantium contains the default set of pre-compiled Ethereum
// contracts used in the Byzantium release.
var PrecompiledContractsByzantium = map[common.Address]PrecompiledContract{
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{1}): &ecrecover{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{2}): &sha256hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{3}): &ripemd160hash{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{4}): &dataCopy{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{5}): &bigModExp{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{6}): &bn256Add{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{7}): &bn256ScalarMul{},
    common.BytesToAddress([]byte{8}): &bn256Pairing{},
}
```

Comment: Here's the link to this code in the master branch:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go

Comment: @RichardHorrocks none of those precompiles can call back another contract right ?