# Assembly call instruction address as single integer

Tags: solidity, assembly

The following function is a function of a **library** (The code is written in Solidity). It has an assembly instruction that I do not understand. Specifically at line `call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60)`.

From the docs:

> `call(g, a, v, in, insize, out, outsize)`
>
> call contract at address a with input mem[in..(in+insize)) providing g
>   gas and v wei and output area mem[out..(out+outsize)) returning 0 on
>   error (eg. out of gas) and 1 on success

```
function addition(G1Point p1, G1Point p2) internal returns (G1Point r) {
        uint[4] memory input;
        input[0] = p1.X;
        input[1] = p1.Y;
        input[2] = p2.X;
        input[3] = p2.Y;
        bool success;
        assembly {
            success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60)
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
            switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        }
        require(success);
    }
```

Why the address field `a` is a simple integer ? Is it referring to an internal library function ? If yes how is the numbering defined ?

Tell me ff you want me to provide the full code of the library.

**EDIT**

I think I found it. Is the address of the a precompiled contract ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to pre-compiled contracts. 6 refers to a the bn256Add pre-compiled contract in the Byzantium release.
You should look for PrecompiledContractsByzantium in the geth source code to find a list of pre-compiled contracts, but this link could help you: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15484/47307