# Puppeth precompile-addresses

Tags: go-ethereum, puppeth

`Should the precompile-addresses (0x1 .. 0xff) be pre-funded with 1 wei? (advisable yes)`

What is the purpose of this, what are precompile-addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...what are precompile-addresses?

The precompiles are a set of contracts that are used for computationally intensive operations that would cost too much gas to implement in the normal way.

There are currently 8 of them. They exist at addresses `0x...01` to `0x...09`.

- [What's a precompiled contract and how are they different from native opcodes?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/440/whats-a-precompiled-contract-and-how-are-they-different-from-native-opcodes)
- [List of pre-compiled contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15479/list-of-pre-compiled-contracts)

> What is the purpose of this (message)...

(Slightly contrary to my original comment, which I've redacted.)

The message/question is output when instantiating a private network with Puppeth.

The [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions) have the following to say. Though only 3 precompiles are mentioned, the same applies to the other 5.

> "When running sha256, ripemd160 or ecrecover on a private blockchain,
>   you might encounter Out-of-Gas. This is because these functions are
>   implemented as “precompiled contracts” and only really exist after
>   they receive the first message (although their contract code is
>   hardcoded). Messages to non-existing contracts are more expensive and
>   thus the execution might run into an Out-of-Gas error. A workaround
>   for this problem is to first send Wei (1 for example) to each of the
>   contracts before you use them in your actual contracts. This is not an
>   issue on the main or test net."

So basically you should answer "yes" to the option of pre-funding if you want to prevent OOG issues when calling the precompiles.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-compiled contracts are implemented in the client nodes, they don't run inside the EVM. They are mainly used for cryptographic applications (the exception is the identity function, which I don't really know the purpose of).

I usually go to the EIP pages to find the gas costs. For example, for the 4 most recent pre-compiled contracts, these are the respective pages:

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-196.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-197.md
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-198.md

They may be buried as well inside the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), but if so they seem to be deep under the surface.

I've written a [whole blog post](http://coders-errand.com/ethereum-support-for-zk-snarks/) about them (from the perspective of cryptographic pairings), which might be helpful to you.