# got response data to nonsencical eth_call request. What is that response?

Tags: eth-call

When I call a seemingly nonsensical transaction on mainnet and rinkeby.

```
ethereum.send('eth_call', [{'from':'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'to':'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002', 'data':''}])
```

I get some result:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0xe3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"}
```

What is that response data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending to `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002` which is the [precompiled contract for SHA256](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15479/list-of-pre-compiled-contracts).

It is returning the SHA256 of data field, which is an empty string, result is `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`.

Comment: When I call eth_getCode on that address I get '0x' response. Which I implied means it is not a contract address. One more convoluted design example of the platform.

Comment: @Sharas Those contracts are pre-compiled contracts and they are implemented in native code by each client, they don't have bytecode.