# How to call sha256 in assembly

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly

I wanna compute `sha256` in Solidity Assembly for hash of getting `bytes` slice.

Answer (score 1):

Sha256 is one of a [few precompiled smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15479/list-of-pre-compiled-contracts):

```
function subSha256(bytes memory data, uint256 offset, uint256 length) public view returns(bytes32) {
    bytes32[1] memory result;
    assembly {
        pop(staticcall(gas, 0x02, add(add(data, 32), offset), length, result, 32))
    }
    return result[0];
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in solc 0.5.x onward, you can simply use `staticcall` at the Solidity level, and get `(bool success, bytes memory result)` returned to you.

Comment: @goodvibration core feature of this code is getting hash for a slice of an array without copying it into separate bytes array.