# staticcall - what does this code do?

Tags: assembly, static-call

I'm lost, does anyone understand this code?

```
        assembly {
            success := staticcall(sub(gas(), 2000), 7, input, 0x80, r, 0x60)
            // Use "invalid" to make gas estimation work
            switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        }
```

Comment: It is calling precompiled contract at address 7 *Scalar multiplication on elliptic curve alt_bn128* (See precompiled contracts list at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15483).

Comment: ahhh, makes sense now.